# How to use PocketSphinx in .NetCore C# running on Raspberry PI?

Tags: .net-core, raspberry-pi, swig, pocketsphinx

I am trying to come up with a version of the pocketsphinx wrapper library which would work on a Raspberry PI running in a .NetCore C# app.

I know that the official Github repo of PocketSphinx suggests SWIG as the best way to port the library in other languages, but all my attempts to have something working are failing.

I have been able to generate "a" wrapper lib, but when I try to actually use it in my app I always come up with a `BadImageFormatException` exception. This makes me think that I am doing something wrong in the process.

Any idea of a way to achieve my goal? A step by step guide about how to do this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a simpler wrapper which calls the PocketSphinx external process and reads the result on the standard output.

The result is pretty quick as well so I am going to stick with this solution.